# How to improve SQL Server cursor performance without rewriting any code?

Tags: sql-server, performance, cursor, database-administration

I have a third party application which is based on Microsoft SQL Server and uses cursors even for simple select queries. It look like .exe file for me and I cannot change anything.

My question is: can I improve somehow performance of this application from SQL Server Database Administrator side? Change some SQL Server configuration parameters and etc.

In other word: can a DBA improve cursor performance without changing source codes of the application?

Some more information and examples.

I have a very simple query like this (I got it from SQL traces).

```
select id, name from my_table
```

there are indexes for `id` and `name` columns. `my_table` has 700 000 records.

If I run it in SQL Server Management Studio it returns first results immediately and fetch all results in 7 seconds.

But this third party application returns first results only after 7 seconds. I compared SQL traces and I found that this third party application use cursor to run this simple query and just return data to the grid. I cannot do much with indexes and etc for this simple example, execution plan is perfect and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably. Look over the query execution plan, create indexes and try run the code again a few times for good meassure.

Typically, it's good to create index and include the columns in it that are used in where, join, having clause. There is a lot of info about this to read up on, it boils down to testing and understanding the execution plans in my experience.

If you cannot change their code, and indexes are in place. Check the fragmentation of the indexes and make sure they are good, else put in a job that rebuilds them each night perhaps.

Another thing, does the server have enough ram memory? So that it can store all the date in ram and not on disk?

Comment: Excuse me, I put some more information and examples to the question description. I cannot do much with indexes, execution plan and etc. It is about how program run SQL queries.

Comment: I added a few things to my answer, the things I came to think about could help.

Comment: Indexes fragmentation I will check. thank you.
About "all data in ram", I think it maybe difficult for me, because data will be grown. but what kind of data do you mean? Only one table, only one DB or what?

May be I can put only temp DB into the memory, but will it help in case of cursor usage?